# Microsoft Access - Variable Overrides in Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently in the process of creating an extensive Access report (~50 calculated fields) for a client and while I've gotten 99% of the report down, I'm having trouble handling the Sum and Count logic on the report.

In a nutshell, the report is intended to list the attendees at an event, tally up the number of attendees at each track/course, and also list any outstanding dues which will be paid at the door. In addition, and this is where I'm having trouble, the report also shows the revenue from each track/course along with a breakdown of the revenue from commuters vs. people staying overnight.

At the moment, all of the formulas follow fairly similar structures so despite having 50 fields, 99% of those are simply adjusting the fields to fit the relevant variables.

For the report now with revenue, my issue is that although I have the fee data specified in the data tables, Microsoft Access keeps zeroing out the calculations rather than displaying the total on the fly.

Here's two of the formals I'm using:
=((Count([W1]))*[Fee Charged W1])
=Sum([Room & Meals])

Earlier today I think I pinpointed the problem to the fact that Microsoft Access is showing the report essentially per individual rather than displaying one report for the entire dataset. I've confirmed this because I manually checked the data and noticed some fields had null values which explained the null tallies.

My question now is whether there is a way to assign a default value for variables in reports so that the report cancels out any invalid data in the database table? I imagine using VBA would help, but I have little experience in that realm.

Thanks very much in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution which was right under my nose the entire time. I just had to configure the fields to use a Running Sum (also called a Cumulative Total).

The answer came right from a page in the Microsoft Office Website: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/summing-in-reports-HA001122444.aspx